# Jumping two blocks high?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I was playing on a gamemode called Lichz on a minecraft multiplayer server, but I got stuck  in a two block deep hole. You cannot build anything on the server. Is it possible to get out?

Edit* After waiting a long time a zombie pigman hit me at the same time I jumped and got out.

Comment: Can you destroy a block or is that also disabled?

Comment: How on earth did a zombie pigman get to you? Were you in the nether?

Comment: Zombie pigmen naturally spawn in the overworld in LichZ

Comment: There used to be a bug on some servers where if you there is enough lag, you can break a block, jump onto where it used to be, and jump up again before it gets replaced. This might work?

Comment: @Kyranstar I posted an answer about how to do it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pretty limited in your options if the server doesn't have a `/unstuck` command. Without this you'll have to:

A: Wait until you starve/attract a passing zed or

B: Have an admin move you.

Good luck!

Comment: in order to accelerate starvation you can jump and run around

Comment: Correction: You can only starve while jumping around. Standing still will not deplete hunger, but it will deplete HP if you are already starving.

Answer (score 12):

Here are your options:

- If there's a horse, a saddled pig, a boat, a minecart or a bed (only during the night) nearby, you can try to right-click it; this will teleport you out of the hole. If you have a boat or minecart with you, you can jump and place it down outside the hole - they are entities, not blocks.
- If you have an Enderpearl, throw it (right-click) to get teleported wherever it lands. Don't throw it straight up or against the hole walls though ...
- If the game has environmental dangers you or other players can manipulate (flowing water or lava into the pit or dropping a single block of gravel or sand into it), you can use it. Same for pushing the *lower* block of the hole into you.
- If the game has custom potions with the "Jump Boost" effect (at least level 2), custom enchanted items with the same, a nearby beacon giving this power or can give you the effect via command blocks, you can use it to gain additional jump ability.
- You can wait for an Ender Dragon to destroy some blocks around the hole, for an Enderman to randomly decide to pick a block off the edge of the hole or a Creeper to blow up nearby. This could be a *long* and potentially deadly wait.

Comment: I should point out that the likelihood of a saddled creature happening to wander by is incredibly rare, ender pearls only serve to attract zombies in LichZ, he's playing on a mp server so he cant spawn items for himself,  and I'm 100% certain that the ender dragon doesn't naturally spawn outside of the end. :p

Comment: @slow_excellence: Well, the horses don't need to be saddled for it to work, in general ... And there are always other players, who can use a lead to bring one nearby.

Answer (score 9):

Being a server admin on a server that prevents building in certain areas, I've found my users to be the best guinea pigs for this kind of question, and Long Ago one of mine introduced me to double-jumping:

With the lag inherent in Minecraft servers, you should be able to jump and place a block beneath yourself. In the split-second that the client allows you to place the block and the server hasn't announced that you can't, you should be able to leap off of it and escape. It takes split-second timing, so don't give up if it doesn't work the first time.

Comment: This won't work if the player doesn't have any blocks handy. It will work though, as I have done this before too.

Comment: Hooray for lag! This however seems to imply that your movement is client side? You should be able to hack your way out in that case.

Comment: Indeed, you can. Movement hacking got so commonplace at one time that Mojang put a bit of code in that does some server-side sanity checking. If it sees some movement that should be impossible, it logs it. If it happens too frequently, the player gets kicked for "moving wrongly". And I've banned players who move wrongly too often.

Comment: yeah there are several ways to abuse the lag :)

Answer (score 4):

If you can break blocks but they immediately respawn, then you can try destroying one block (the upper one) while jumping against it if you do it correctly you are stuck between the lower block and the upper block. After that you simply have to jump once **without pressing any direction keys** and voila, you are free! 
Works for me on almost all servers I have been to and can be "abused" for several other things.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're probably going to have to get ahold of a moderator or an admin on the server. Jumping two blocks high is not possible unless you use the `/effect` command to give yourself a jump boost.